# Examples of quadtrees with datasets

Tags: tree, dataset, quadtree

I don’t know if this is the right place to write about my question. However my question is this: I’m trying to find examples of quadtree implementations using real datasets. The only ones I find online are using random Points and not with real data. Are there any example available that uses datasets? (I don’t have any issue with what programming language is used)
Thank you

Comment: Any geospatial dataset would be good. You can search them on google.

Answer (score 0):

(Self advertisement) The [TinSpin project](https://github.com/tzaeschke/TinSpin) uses a variety of spatial indexes, including quadtrees, on a variety of datasets, including an OpenStreetMap sample representing the Alps. Results can be found [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/TinSpin/blob/master/doc/benchmark-2017-01/Diagrams.pdf).

The quadtree is implemented [here](https://github.com/tzaeschke/tinspin-indexes/blob/master/src/main/java/org/tinspin/index/qtplain/QuadTreeKD0.java).

Comment: Could you please send me the link of the class that has the quadtree implemented?

Comment: I added a link.